# lua inside function appears segfault

Tags: c, lua

code:

```
    m_L = luaL_newstate();
    if(m_L==NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    luaL_openlibs(m_L);
```

I use gdb to test my code, when it runs to luaL_openlibs(m_L); 
gdb tell me that 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
luaH_getstr (t=0x7fa950, key=0x7cc2e0) at ltable.c:458
458      if (ttisstring(gkey(n)) && rawtsvalue(gkey(n)) == key))
I don't knwo how to fix it. Please help me out.

Comment: just check the prototype of `luaL_openlibs(m_L)`, is `m_L` the correct type ?

Comment: There is no promble with the type of m_L

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code shown. Your problem is necessarily in code *not* shown, so it's impossible for us to answer. Perhaps you've got code before this that corrupts the stack. Perhaps you're dynamically loading the wrong version of Lua. You need to start eliminating variables until the crash goes away. I'd start with this code and *only* this code, nothing else, and statically link in the Lua library. If that still crashes, you've got much more serious problems.